# How to display only one series on Altair chart

Tags: legend, interactive, altair

For the interactive legend example, I was wondering if there is a way to display only one series and hide others on the chart after running the code. Then, when clicking on the legend, the chart can change to highlight different series.

The current example code displays all series at first, then highlights different series when clicking on the legend.

Here is the example code:

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.unemployment_across_industries.url

selection = alt.selection_multi(fields=['series'], bind='legend')

alt.Chart(source).mark_area().encode(
    alt.X('yearmonth(date):T', axis=alt.Axis(domain=False, format='%Y', tickSize=0)),
    alt.Y('sum(count):Q', stack='center', axis=None),
    alt.Color('series:N', scale=alt.Scale(scheme='category20b')),
    opacity=alt.condition(selection, alt.value(1), alt.value(0.2))
).add_selection(
    selection
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the `init` argument of the selection; for example:

```python
selection = alt.selection_multi(fields=['series'], bind='legend', init=[{'series': 'Agriculture'}])
```